# Windows 10: Issue With Clock While Using Custom Font

Tags: windows-10, fonts, taskbar, clock

I am having trouble with the digital clock in the taskbar on Windows 10 when using a custom font. The colon appears as a square (invalid character). I've tried Clear Sans and FreeSans; regular, light, and medium styles of each. All of them do have a colon character directly in the font.

Is this expected behavior, or is there a fix?

Comment: Is it appear for a specific type of font? See this registry values `sShortTime` and `sTimeFormat` in [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International] . Reply what you see!

Comment: Hey @Biswa! Thanks for the reply. In those two values, I see the colon symbol appearing correctly. I have not changed the system font back, yet. [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/N3LEt)

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing this as well. Based on the thread below, I believe this is a bug with custom fonts in the Windows 10 Creators Update. The linked post has a workaround of changing the unicode character used for colon.

In short, use U+A789 as the separator in HKCU\ControlPanel\International > sShortTime.

https://www.tenforums.com/installation-upgrade/82691-win-10-pro-creators-update-taskbar-clock-anomaly-any-suggestions.html#post1027583

Comment: Worked like a charm on Windows 10 Pro, 1809. Thanks!